# How to center list items in my navigation bar

Tags: html, css, listitem

I'm having some trouble centering the list items on my website using CSS3, any idea why I cant get the items to center?

Below is a screenshot of my problem:
https://gyazo.com/4b68df7e38e71ae320fdb6cb1c0c4e87

Below is the CSS3 and HTML code that I have written for my nav bar:

```css
.navigation ul {
  background-color: #A1C9EC;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #9FABB6;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #9FABB6;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!--Wrapper to adjust width of main body on desktop site.-->
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Shane's Portfolio</h1>
  <!--Navigation Bar (TOP)-->
  <div class="navigation">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>My Work</li>
        <li>Qualifications</li>
        <li>About Me</li>
        <li>Contact Me</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please also share your HTML. Edit your question and click on the `<>` to create a working example of what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
text-align: center;
padding-left: 0;
```

to the `.navigation ul {` `<ul>`s have default padding this is why you need to set it to `0`.

(Also I've shortened the navigation list and words just to have the right output if you click on "Run code snipped")

```css
.navigation ul{
    background-color: #A1C9EC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #9FABB6;
    border-width: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.navigation ul li 
{
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #9FABB6;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Shane's Portfolio</h1>
  <!--Navigation Bar (TOP)-->
  <div class="navigation">
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li>Home</li>
              <li>My</li>
              <li>Qua</li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, rookie mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align: center;
```

on a wrapper div should do the trick. if you can share the html code it would be easy to give answer